# example of a positive function-riemann stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a positive function f on $[0,1]$ such that $f\in R([0,1])$ but 
$1/f \notin R([0,1])$
Thanks for your help

Comment: What is $\,R([0,1])\,$?

Comment: riemann integrable

Comment: Then what's the Riemann-Stieltjes integral to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2&x\neq\frac{1}{2}\\8&x=\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

The above is Riemann integrable in $\,[0,1]\,$ ,  but $\,\displaystyle{\frac{1}{f(x)}}\,$ is not (why?)

Comment: I edited my first answer since at first I didn't notice the positiveness requirement